# Figuring out how to take N and let reshape automatically assign to np.array(size(N)).reshape(N, N)

Tags: python-3.x

A friend would like ndarray.reshape to figure out how many columns are needed given that she'd like N values to be formed into R rows. She speculates that perhaps just providing one argument to reshape might cause the other to default, but it doesn't. For example, she tried to get three rows of four columns like this:

```
np.array(range(12)).reshape(3)
```

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12 into shape (3,)

What could she do to get the number of rows automatically calculated?

I've read the numpy.reshape documentation.  I tried testing, but none of them look like anything automatic except:

Comment: Sorry I tried providing an example but I'm fairly new to this site and programming.

Comment: `np.array(range(N)).reshape(R, (N / R))` and maybe some code to make sure N is divisible by R (or just take the ceiling of the division and cast it to int). Also look up `np.arange`.